# Strange behaviour with activity type in search builder

Tags: search-results, search-builder

One of our users reported a strange phenomenon when using search builder. I recreated this on the demo site.

When searching for activity type = Meeting I don't get results:

[image: Search Builder doesnt work with =]

When searching for activity type like "Meeting" I get (correct) results:
[image: Search builder works with like]

I have similar problems with activity status. Using 'like' works in some cases, but I can't use '=' or 'in'.

Can anyone reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the behavior; it seems like a bug, can you post a bug report here:  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel

Comment: Thanks, it certainly looks like one. I was just surprised no one noticed this before us. I'll report the bug asap.

Answer (score 1):

Well as per my recent fixes in Search Builder, atleast I have changed the column Title to clarify whether a element expects a string value or int. Like in this particular case you will have Activity Type( expects string value as 'Label') and Activity Type ID(integer value as activity_type_id), but that fix was partial. So the error is occurring due to faulty select element which you used to select value against '=' operator as it is in ('id' => 'label') format and the expected format would be ('label' => 'label'). And the underlying fix it needs will be major.